# What is the meaning of "Closed Short" ,“Opened Long” ,"Scaled Out" and "Scaled In"?

Tags: foreign-exchange

I wonder if "Opened Long" and "Closed Short" mean "sell" at forexfactory.com?

What about "Scaled Out" and "Scaled In"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Opened Long** - is when you open a long position. Long means that you buy to open the position, so you are trying to profit as the price rises. So if you were closing a long position you would sell it.

**Closed Short** - is when you close out a short position. Short means that you sell to open and buy back to close. With a short position you are trying to profit as the price falls.

**Scaled Out** - means you get out of a position in increments as the price climbs (for long positions).

**Scaled In** - means you set a target price and then invest in increments as the stock falls below that price (for long positions).